# True diameter of black holes?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity, event-horizon

It's currently estimated that a black of ten solar masses would have a diameter (i.e. an event horizon) of about 30 kilometres or so. I've been recently considering black holes from a quantum gravity perspective and I'm wondering to what extent this apparent diameter could just be an illusion. My thought was that, if light escaping, or being reflected from black holes, is being condensed by a field of fermions surrounding it, then it may give the illusory effect that the event horizons' diameter is larger than it actually is since the wavelength(s) of the emitted/reflected photons would be increasing in proportion to the increased distance from the event horizon. This is all rather speculative, but I was thinking that the true diameter of an event horizon (if a singularity really is there, and if it really is infinitely dense) might be more like the diameter of a proton, or something. Perhaps even smaller.

Perhaps as an adjunct to this I ought to briefly elaborate on my idea concerning singularities: I was thinking that infinities of density may certainly be possible in the cores of black holes since they operate within a special case so far as the universe is concerned, i.e. they operate beyond the bounds of relativistic physics (underpinned by fermionic fields whereby the minima of measurable space is determined by Planck's constant) and hence finite masses compacted within infinitesimal of 'space' may be possible.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I don't quite follow your question. Generally speaking, when people talk about the radius of a black hole, it is a fairly straightforward calculation within general relativity (such as the Schwartzchild solution); no quantum effects needed. There could theoretically be quantum effects near the boundary which might make some "apparent" measurement more complicated, but we haven't probed that close. I'm probably missing something more specific in your question though?

Comment: " since the wavelength(s) of the emitted/reflected photons would be increasing in proportion to the increased distance from the event horizon." could you elaborate why this would happen?

Comment: A pertinent question may be what "diameter" actually means in this context, and how "apparent" diameter differs from the "true" diameter - what does it mean for a thing to appear larger than it actually is, when that appearance is the entirety of the known phenomenon? The same goes for "density" - how does "infinite density" differ from the mere absence of a frontier which defines the extent of an inside place for a phenomenon as distinct from the outside?

Comment: "is being condensed by a field of fermions surrounding it," why the fermions effect on space time would differ from the  spacetime distortion of the black hole, anyway?

Comment: Light doesn't escape from a black hole. A 10 $M_\odot$ BH has a Schwarzschild radius $r_s\approx 29.54$ km. But it's best *not* to think of that as the distance from the EH (event horizon) to the centre. It's defined as the circumference of the EH (measured in Schwarzschild coordinates) divided by $2\pi$.

Comment: @PM2Ring still we can think of a ball, as "seen" from outside, with the normal volume... while points inside have their own distance from the singularity (or whatever there is/isn't at centre). Right?

Comment: Where to begin, firstly, PM2Ring, light does escape from a black hole, it escapes as Hawking radiation. anna v, the fermions would be standing in for spacetime. Steve, that's roughly what I was getting at. However, the infinity of density would not come in the absence of a frontier. The frontier would be the event horizon.

Comment: anna v, Certainly. In my quantum gravity model, the force of gravity corresponds to an increasing density of fermions surrounding classical, massive objects. These fermions are electrons. These stand-in for spacetime and generate the effects of spacetime (among other things). As light approaches points of higher and higher density it falls into superpositions with a larger and larger number of other photons until, by the time it's anywhere near the event horizon, it's best understood as a gamma particle.

Comment: anna v (continued), By the time it reaches the event horizon a 'photon' wouldn't even, recognisably, be a wave; it would have fallen into some sort of plasma, I imagine. Conversely, as photons escape the clutches of the black hole's gravitational field their measurable characteristics would take on more recognisable dimensions and give the illusion that the black hole itself has dimensions measuring, for instance, kilometres. Due to this effect of length contraction (even of light) near the event horizon I suspect that a true estimate of the event horizons diameter's much smaller than it seems

Comment: @SamCottle: without a concrete mathematical model, none of this can be evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

The true diameter of a black hole is that which determines a surface beyond which not even light escapes.